# Jquery custom function not positioning divs on ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, callback, positioning

I have written a custom function that positions absolute divs inside a container calculating the top positions and heights:

```
$.fn.gridB = function() {
    var o = $(this); //EDITED from var o = $(this[0]);
    o.each(function() {
        var a1top = o.find('.article1').position().top;
        var a1height = o.find('.article1').height();
        var a0top = o.find('.article0').position().top;
        var a0height = o.find('.article0').height();
        var a2top = o.find('.article2').position().top;
        var a2height = o.find('.article2').height();
        var a3height = o.find('.article3').height();
        var a4height = o.find('.article4').height();
        var a5height = o.find('.article5').height();
        if (a0height > a1height + a1top) {
            $('.article3', o).css('top', a0top + a0height + 20);
        } else if (a0height < a1height + a1top) {
            $('.article3', o).css('top', a1top + a1height + 20);
        }
        $('.article4', o).css('top', a2top + a2height + 20);
        $('.article5', o).css('top', a2top + a2height + 20);
        $('.article6', o).css('top', a2top + a2height + a5height + 40);
        $('.article7', o).css('top', a2top + a2height + a5height + 40);
        var lastChildPos = o.find('div:last-child').position().top;
        var lastChildHeight = o.find('div:last-child').height();
        o.height(lastChildPos + lastChildHeight + 20);
    });
};​
```

The container has a class ".fours" and the srcipt works perfect on window load. But when it is called after an ajax infinite scroll load it fails to position the absolute divs correctly inside the next ".fours" container:

```
function loadArticle(pageNumber) {
    $('a#inifiniteLoader').fadeIn('fast');
    $.ajax({
        url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no=" + pageNumber + '&loop_file=loop',
        success: function(html) {
            $('a#inifiniteLoader').fadeOut('1000');
            $("#content").append(html); // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
            $('.fours:last').preloader_index();
            $('.fours').gridB(); // EDITED from $('.fours:last').gridB();
            $('.article a').on({
                mouseenter: function() {
                    if (!$('.preloader', $(this).parent('.article')).length > 0) {
                        $(this).stop().css('opacity', '1');
                    }
                },
                mouseleave: function() {
                    if (!$('.preloader', $(this).parent('.article')).length > 0) {
                        $(this).stop().css('opacity', '0');
                        $('.article-info', $(this).parent('.article')).stop().fadeTo(200, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}​
```

There is something wrong but i'm pretty close. If i put .fours:last when i call the function gridB() after the success of ajax the script calculates only the top position of the divs ignoring the heights. If i remove :last the script does not calculate both top position and heights.

Any help?

**EDIT:** Here is an example of the related HTML. Another div with class

```
 <div id="content">
<div class="fours">
  <div class="article article0">
     <div><img src="url" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="article article1">
     <div><img src="url" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="article article2">
     <div><img src="url" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="article article3">
     <div><img src="url" /></div>
  </div>
  </div>
<!-- Next ".fours" div is loaded here with ajax function -->
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**: In the gridB function I changed the line var o = $(this[0]); to var o = $(this); and changed function call from $('.fours:last').gridB(); to $('.fours').gridB();. It worked but now the script positions all absolute div's inside the ajax loaded next sets with the values of the first set of articles. I think it's closer to the solution. There must be a way to target the container loaded by ajax. :last does not work.

Comment: Could you post the related HTML?

Comment: Hi Juan, i posted the HTML code please check the EDIT on my question. Have a suggestion in mind?

Comment: I think there's still a lot of information missing, for example, what's the html returned from the Ajax call? What is the `preloader_index()` call doing? Also you mention that this should work with an Ajax infinite loop, but you seem to have fixed class names for articles 0 through 7. I don't see how the code is working for articles beyond 7.

Comment: Yes i guess it looks pretty complex. I'll try to explain if it will be of any help for a suggestion. The html returned from ajax is another div container with class .four with the same number of divs with the same classes  (.article0 - .article7) tested and worked without the infinite scroll call. preloader_index() is fading in the images contained in the article div's, i tried the script without it and  there is no conflict, div's are still positioned wrong. And finally there are no articles beyond 7, they are loaded in sets of 7 inside the '.fours' container. Hope this clears it a bit?

Comment: I guess the problem is that the gridB() function is not targeting the .fours container added by the ajax load?

Comment: I've debugged the code and that seems to be right, I'm trying to get a representative example working in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vxnHL/5/

Comment: Thanks for the input Juan. Please check my second edit on my question which i think is closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the comment in your last edit you could do the following to reference the last `<div class="fours" />` added:

```
success: function(html) {
    var $html = $(html);                       // Wrap HTML in jQuery object.
    $('a#inifiniteLoader').fadeOut('1000');
    $("#content").append($html);               // Add created object.

    $html.preloader_index();                   // Use the same object.
    $html.gridB();                             // Call gridB using the same object.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help juan. The JQuery object worked for the append and preloader function but not for the grid one. It still messed the layout of the loaded content. There was a longer way round, i used the resize plugin and placed the grid function for each '.fours' in a resize event of the #content and it works ok now. I'd still like to have the grid function to work only for the loaded content instead of recalculating the previous content but for now i'm going to keep it there.